# Go gin: how to read multiple route segments at all?

Tags: go, go-gin

I add a PUT /:folder route to create a folder

I need a PUT /:folder/:path/to/final/file, to be used when user post a new file. So I have the root in the first paramer, but I don't know how to create a route handling 'n' routes segments and the read as a single string

For example callling

```
PUT /cats
```

will create folder named cats. This is already working

I need

```
PUT /cats/milady/first-year/32312.jpg
```

to identify 'cats' as first parameter, it's my user first-level-folder
and then get mylady/first-year as nested subfolders to check and create if needed

and the 32312.jpg a filename

I ask you kindly how to setup route using gin
PUT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer.

I can create group, so under a group I can use the asterisk for 'undefined level of path'

```
superGroup := router.Group("/:folder")
{
        
    // Create a folder
    superGroup.PUT("", createFolder)

    // Save file into folder
    superGroup.PUT("/*full-path", uploadFile)
}
```

Then I can read the `full-path` and the `folder`

```
func uploadFile(c *gin.Context) {

    folder:= c.Param("folder")
    fullPath := c.Param("full-path")

    ....

    c.Status(http.StatusOK)
}
```